# Connect to Databricks properly using a Bitbucket pipeline to run tests

Tags: bitbucket, databricks, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bunch of tests I want to run and pass before merging into main. I have a Bitbucket pipeline that runs, however it throws the following error:
`RuntimeError: Only remote Spark sessions using Databricks Connect are supported. Could not find connection parameters to start a Spark remote session.`

Running these tests locally, works fine. Clearly the issue is with connecting to the spark session remotely so what I tried in the pipeline is the following:

```
image: python:3.11

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    main:
      - step:
          name: "Setup and Test"
          script:
            # Install Python dependencies
            - pip install -r requirements.txt

            # Configure Databricks Connect
            - echo -e "$DATABRICKS_HOST\n$DATABRICKS_TOKEN\n$DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID\n$DATABRICKS_ORG_ID" | databricks-connect configure

            # Install and run pytest
            - pip install pytest
            - pytest tests/
```

Where the creds are correctly parsed in through the env variables in Bitbucket. This did not work and gives the same error.

How do I connect to databricks so my tests can run properly on the connected session.